# Caffeine cache, how to get value that expired?

Tags: java, spring, caching, cache-expiration

There is a task, to get an element from the cache if there is no access to the database. If the token has expired. How can I get an expired cache element? Is there any cache for Spring which can do it?

Comment: Perhaps consider using a [RemovalListener](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Removal)?

Comment: if we will use RemovalListener, we need to store removal elements before use their